# Postgres RDS : Freeable Storage Space is going down

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

In one of my Postgres Replica (AWS RDS), i am seeing big up and downs in Freeable Storage Space which is very weird. 2 days back, it came down to zero 
and when i queried the size of tables (in schema), it was close(but still 100gb less). I thought it might be taking some space so increased space to 1500 GB. 
Within one day i received alarms that there is not storage left again in this replica. Looking at the size of schema/tables they show only 800GB. I am guessing
somewhere generated logs are taking space inside RDS. Is there any way to find the root cause? 
 [image: With in one day from 800GB to 0]

Comment: 800GB logs is doubtful, unless you mean write ahead logs - then - possible (but would mean significant lag on slave node I suppose), most suitable reason - temporary table... would explain momentary drop of used space and slow growth

Comment: We are using some queries which have joins, do you mean those queries are using some temporary table which is resulting into this extra WAL?

Comment: no, I don't. those all are separate possible reasons